Prisoner draws on wall, escapes using a pen
So I remember this movie about a prisoner in a jail or mental institute who was involved in some trial, or has to give testimony or some other important activity, I don't recall. There's a moment in the movie when the main character visits him in his cell and finds the prisoner drawing something big on the wall/walls of his cell. I think it involved something about the history of mankind, I recall something about Africa and the origin of men ("this is where it all began, in Africa" -approximate quote), but it was only a small part of the bigger picture. I think he was supposed to be released for his part in the trial/testimony/activity, but they didn't release him. Somewhat later, after the trial/testimony/activity, the prisoner returns to his cell only to find that the guards have painted over his drawing, in order to mock him, and this was (I think) the thing that triggered the man to what comes next.
The other thing that I remember is that towards the end of the movie, the prisoner steals a pen from the protagonist and uses it to scratch away the wall around a window and escape. However I am not sure if the actual escape is depicted or only suggested. I might have seen the movie 10ish years ago, but I am certain it is a bit older that, as local TV channels rarely show any movies within 5 years of their release. 
The movie was most certainly american, english language, i saw it on a romanian channel with romanian subtitles. I was too young to understand the movie, so i can't really remember details. Since i have posted the question i've been thinking about it more and more, and some details have popped into my mind; i'm constantly editing the question with further details

Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I believe you may be looking for the 1999 movie Instinct starring Cuba Gooding Jr and Anthony Hopkins.

Nearly two years after having gone amiss in Africa, renowned anthropologist Dr. Ethan Powell is caught committing a crime and subsequently imprisoned in a Florida mental institution, where aspiring psychiatrist Dr. Theo Calder takes over his important case. Dr. Powell, who has been with a group of gorillas during all that time, is not talking at all and seems to be living in a dreamworld. Very slowly, Dr. Calder manages to reach Ethan Powell and starts finding out why Ethan killed two of the poachers. Yet Theo's case is not just about why the murders have happened, but also about how Dr. Powell became the being he is in the first place. With Ethan's silence broken, Theo is introduced into a world beyond common human comprehension: The true nature of being. He learns that mankind's control of everything is a mere illusion and that the true values of existence can't be found so easily. Ethan changes Theo's view of things forever.

Here is an image of the cell drawings:

At the end of the film (Spoiler):

 He gets a hearing to reveal the truth, but an attack by a vicious guard on the other prisoners causes Powell to stop talking again. At the end of the film, Powell escapes from prison using a pen to dig out the lock on a window, and heads back to Africa.

Here is the trailer:



